# How to save first_name and last_name after sending invitation with devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

Is there a way to add first_name and last_name of person you are inviting with devise invitable and save these attributes in the database? in application-controller.rb i have

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation).concat [:first_name, :last_name]
```

and i also tried

```
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
     u.permit(:first_name, :last_name)
```

but none of these are saving first name last_name in the database when user is created after invitation is sent. just email is saved.

i have copied devise_invitable views and im working off of those.
i am using 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.6'
thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)?

Comment: yes i have. but this is devise_invitable specific

Comment: You are right.. I'm sorry, I don't know why it's happening.. This devise_invitable is a little confusing..